# How to select distinct on one column while returning other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have two columns in the database:

```
Value | Date
---------------------
1.3   | 1410374280000
```

Value is a float and Date is an epoch integer in milliseconds

I am trying to optimize this query as this returns a few thousand rows.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= [some_time_in_the_past]
```

Since I am rendering a chart on the front end, I need far fewer data points. So I am truncating the date.

```
SELECT data.date / 5000 * 5000 AS truncated, data.price FROM data
WHERE date >= [some_time_in_the_past]
```

This above truncates the date to every 5 seconds. So now I want to `SELECT DISTINCT` on it.

However:

```
SELECT DISTINCT truncated, price
```

This will SELECT DISTINCT on both the truncated_date as well as the price. Is there a way to only SELECT DISTINCT on the truncated date and get the price column too.

Comment: First you show a table with a column named `Value`, then you continue with a column named `price`? Also `"get the price column too"` doesn't define what you want. Obviously, you want to fold sets of rows with the same truncated timestamp into one. You have to define *which* price to pick from the set. First, last, avg, random, arbitrary pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick an arbitrary price with [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) for each set of identical `truncated` (which fits your non-existing definition):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       (date / 5000) * 5000 AS truncated, price
FROM   data
WHERE  date >= [some_time_in_the_past]
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Add more `ORDER BY` expressions to pick something more specific, like @Clodoaldo already provided.

Answer (score 0):

[`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select distinct on (truncated) *
from (
    select data.date / 5000 * 5000 as truncated, data.price
    from data
    where date >= [some_time_in_the_past]
) s
order by truncated, price desc
```

If you want the lowest price change from `price desc` to `price asc`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a possible solution is to group by the truncated date column and calculate the average of the price column:

```
SELECT truncated,
       AVG(price)
  FROM data
 GROUP
    BY truncated
```